# Discord.NET Guild.DefaultChannel does not work

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I am coding a discord bot, and I want it to send a message to a server default channel whenever the bot joins a new server.

Here is my code

```
client.JoinedGuild += async guild =>
{
var channel = guild.DefaultChannel;
await channel.SendMessageAsync("test");
};
```

The error occurs on `channel.SendMessageAsync`, and when I debugged the program, it keeps showing that `channel` is null even though I do have a default channel in my server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A discord update months ago removed `defaultChannel` property. Which means that servers now do not need to have a default channel at all.
(You can even delete all channel in your server!)

Which also means `Guild.DefaultChannel` property will not work as intended anymore.
(Correct me if I am wrong, but if a server still has a `#general` channel, the property will work as intended.)

Discord.NET v2+ have a working `DefaultChannel` property. (It uses its own set of algorithm to determine which would be the default channel for the guild.)

The source code for the algorithm is [here](https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net/blob/dev/src/Discord.Net.WebSocket/Entities/Guilds/SocketGuild.cs#L66-L69). (Line 66-69)

Looking at the algorithm, you may want to be slightly cautious about using it, if your bot have permission to send messages everywhere, the `DefaultChannel` property would simply be the first channel in the server's channel list.
(And it would be bad news if that was a readme channel)